# SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: xml, spring, mongodb, rest, maven

I am performing CRUD operations on MongoDB using SPRING REST api. But I am getting the following error:

```
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/avarshney/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HelloSpringWithMongoDB' did not find a matching property.
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 991 ms
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 17, 2015 2:35:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/HelloSpringWithMongoDB] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 17, 2015 2:35:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4267 ms
```

Here's my **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.manishchhabra.blog</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloSpringWithMongoDB</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>HelloSpringWithMongoDB Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>HelloSpringWithMongoDB</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Heres my **web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<display-name>Spring With MongoDB Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>
```

Here's my **dispatcher-servelet.xml** (WEB_INF/jsp/dispatcher-servelet.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.manishchhabra.blog" />

<!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="localhost" />
</bean>

<!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and querying the documents in the database -->
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
</bean>

<!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in 
    @Repository annotated classes -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />


<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

I am using Tomcat v7.0 to run this on local server and I have added the necessary jars in WEB_INF/lib in the deployment assembly. Please advise as to what to do in order to run the code.

**EDIT:** Edited the stacktrace to show all the messages.

**EDIT 2 :** Edited the pom.xml to change Spring to 4.1.5 release

Comment: Looks like part of the stacktrace at the end is omitted. Please share the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Edited it. Please have a look.

Comment: Please let us know the Java and Spring version that you are using.

Comment: Java: Version 8 Update 40 (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Spring framework: version 3.2.0 release

Comment: @aayush_v20, Can you increase the log level to debug/trace and send complete logs?

Comment: @user3247727: Can you advice me how to do that since I cannot figure out how to change the log level

Comment: @aayush_v20, do you have log4j.properties in your application?

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-logging).

Answer (score 3):

You need to delete the double entry in web.xml file for

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

This tag appears twice in web.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade to Spring 4 to work with Java 8 byte code format.

Comment: Meaning I just need to change the version in my pom.xml right? I am new to this so please ignore the triviality of the question.

Comment: I tried it and updated the pom.xml to change spring to 4.1.5.RELEASE but still the following error exists : **'SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'**

Comment: Just for confirmation, did you run `mvn clean install` before starting the server?

Comment: Yes. I did that. Although, I am using Spring Tool Suite which I refreshed and then ran the code again using option 'Run on server'

Comment: Is it failing because of the same `at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)` error?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to check recently added jars in lib folder because of this you face this kind off issue remove the jar and try to run, if work fine find the alternative of jar which on create an issue